# DAX expression to return filtered dates from an other column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a column in my dataset that are dates of when an application was created. I would like to make a new a column to give me a count of applications that are over 90 days old. Idealy it would just return a 1 if that date in the row is older than 90 days and a blank if its younger.

I assume the easiest way to achieve this would be with a DAX expression but im also open to a Power Query formula.

I tried: New Column = CALCULATE ( DATESBETWEEN (Arive[Date Created], NOW()-90, NOW()))

I was trying to get it to populate the column with the dates in that range then I could simply quick measure to get a count. It did not work.

"It says multipule values supplied where a single value was expected".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the difference you may want to use:

```
New Column = DATEDIFF ( Arive[Date Created], TODAY (), DAY )
```

This can be wrapped in a comparison for the 90 days:

```
New Column = INT ( DATEDIFF ( Arive[Date Created], TODAY (), DAY ) > 90 )
```

In PowerQuery:

```
Duration.Days(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())-Date.From([Date Created]))
```

Comment: DATESBETWEEN works in a different way than what you want here: “ Returns a table that contains a column of dates that begins with a specified start date and continues until a specified end date.
This function is suited to pass as a filter to the CALCULATE function. Use it to filter an expression by a custom date range.” [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datesbetween-function-dax)

Comment: New Column = INT ( DATEDIFF ( Arive[Date Created], TODAY (), DAY ) > 90 ) - This worker perfectly! Thank you for your help and the additional info!